# Azure DevOps: Access Junit Pass-Rate in Pipeline

Tags: junit, azure-pipelines

In my pipeline I have a step such as:

```
  - script: |
      python -m pytest --junit-xml=$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/logs/TEST-LOCAL.xml $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/packages/* || true
    displayName: 'Unit-Test'
```

If all tests are fine, I would like to execute a deployment action within the pipeline. How could I check if all Unit test were succesfull?

Comment: Publish the test results to the pipeline and configure it to fail the pipeline if tests have failed. If the pipeline fails, it won't run any subsequent steps.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that? I know how to publish, but how can i check them?

Comment: Look at the documentation for the `PublishTestResults` step.

Comment: found it: please add your comments as answer so that i can accept